CMake targeting Android: how to specify targeting API?
I have a CMake project, where CMakeLists.txt has:
target_compile_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        -target aarch64-linux-android10000
        )

When I run cmake as:
cmake -S xxx -B yyy \
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Android" \
    -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH="arm64" \
    -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI="arm64-v8a" \
    -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=$NDK \
    -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang \
    -DANDROID_STL=c++_static \
    -DSKIP_TESTS=ON \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON  && \

the cmake produces the following message (among other messages):
-- Android: Targeting API '21' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'

Here we see Targeting API '21'.
Then I run make and see that clang++ is called with options --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 ... $(CXX_FLAGS) where $(CXX_FLAGS) contains -target aarch64-linux-android10000.
The core question: how to specify targeting API so that cmake produces the following message:
-- Android: Targeting API '10000' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'

and so the clang++ is called with --target=aarch64-linux-android10000 (rather than --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21)?

Extra question: What is the meaning of 10000 in the triple aarch64-linux-android10000?
